# Difference between process group id and job id in UNIX

Tags: unix, process

Please tell me the difference between a process group ID and a jobid. Is jobid a builtin of a shell program or is it related to the kernel? What are the uses of each of them? When a process is run in background, is only jobid set or is the pgid set as well?
What are the uses of the setpgid() function?

When a process is run in background, is the kernel also involved or does the shell take care of which is background or foreground?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good questions. The job id is mostly just a shell construct. There is support in the kernel in the form of the signals that are involved in job control, and the way in which the kernel knows exactly which processes to send the job control signals to.

Strictly speaking, the answer to your first question is that the job id is purely a shell creation. It exists because a pipeline (or, rarely, another shell grouped construct) may consist of multiple processes that should be controlled as a unit.

To answer your last question, the shell starts all processes by first doing a `fork(2)` and then doing an `execve(2)`. The only difference with `&` is that the shell does not do a `wait(2)` (or a related variant) and so the program can continue "in the background". There is actually little distinction in Unix between foreground and background.

The process group is an association defined by shells so that the kernel knows about a single "foreground" process that handles a set of various "background" processes. This is mainly important so that the background processes will generate a signal should they decide to suddenly read from a terminal. (Such terminal probably being connected to standard input.) This will cause the "job" to generate a signal and the shell will prompt the user to do something.

Try `(sleep 5; read x)&` and after 6 seconds type a return or something so that the shell wakes up. That's when you see something like...

> [1]+  Stopped                 ( sleep 5; read x )

...and you then type `fg` to pull it into the foreground.

Originally, Unix had pipelines, and it had `&`, but there was no way to move a command or pipeline between foreground and background and no way to help a background process that suddenly decided to read standard input.

Job control and the kernel support for it were added by Bill Joy and others in early versions of BSD and csh(1). These were picked up line-for-line by commercial Unix and in cloned for the work-alike Linux kernel.

---

Regarding the questions about process groups and `ps(1)`...
In order to support job control in shells, the kernel process state includes a process group ID and a session ID. A *process group* and a *job* are the same thing, but a *job number* is just a handle the shell makes up. A process is a session leader if the session ID is the same as the pid, and a process is a process group leader if the pgid is the same as the pid. I believe something a bit more subtle is happening with the `+` that `ps(1)` prints. Each terminal knows what its foreground process group is, so I believe a process gets a + if pid == pgid && (pgid is the foreground pg for its controlling terminal).

In summary, the kernel keeps several items of state: pid, pgid, sid, and a process may have a controlling terminal and a terminal may have a foreground pgid. These credentials are mostly intended to support job control but are also used to revoke access to a terminal when a user logs out.

Comment: In ur example for process group, what is the use of process group. PLease explani in detail how process group is involved.

Comment: One more thing, u have written that foreground process controls background processes, can u give me an example of this?

Comment: Sorry one more doubt, u wrote that job id is built in of shell, so foreground / background is understanding of shell but when we do "ps" then it display in stats as "R" or "R+" as foreground nad background process but ps is executed by kernel so how does kernel know that job is back/foreground.